# Unsure if 'adb push' has completed correctly in recovery mode

Tags: rooting, adb

I did everything that the CyanogenMod wiki told me to, and I think I might be done, and I got this alert on my computer.

[image]

But I'm not getting any alerts on ClockWorkMod.... I'm using the international Samsung SIII.
Please tell me what's going, and what I can do to fix it if I screwed up. Thanks!

Comment: The phone doesn't give you any kind of notification when `adb push` finishes. What steps are you following, exactly? Is there something you're expecting to happen at this point?

Comment: Oh, good! This was my question. So, it's finished? Thanks for getting to me so quickly dude

Answer (score 0):

After that line `(X bytes in Y seconds)` appears, transfer has been completed.